# cURL csv file submission returning OK status but no data is uploaded

Tags: php, curl, laravel-5.1

I'm having difficulty uploading a .csv file through a cURL request to a RESTful API. I'm receiving a successful response (*200 OK*) but no data appears to be submitted:

```
{
  "meta": [
  ],
  "code": 200,
  "object": "csvfile",
  "data": [
  ],
  "time": 1472464675
}
```

This is being made with the following request. I've added commenting to break down each of the `CURL_SETOPTS`:

```
    // create a CURLFile object
    $cfile = curl_file_create($fileName,'text/csv', $fileName);

    // start curl request
    $curl = curl_init();

    // assign POST data
    $data = array('file' => $cfile);

    // specify POST request
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    // basic auth
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, getenv('USERNAME').':'.getenv('PASSWORD'));

    // destination URI
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.arestfulapi.com');

    // associate curlfile
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    // since we're using PHP 5.6 we need to enable CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, true);

    // return options
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, $out);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    // debugging
    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        echo("CURL RESPONSE: ");
        echo $response;
    }
    curl_close($curl);
```

I should mention I don't fully understand the importance of the `$postname` field in CURLfile objects. Furthermore I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing by `assign POST data` as demonstrated in the construct's documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php).

Note: I'm writing this in a Laravel application and am aware of the Guzzle client but have opted to present the problem this way, as there's more support for typical cURL problems on SO. I believe the issue is something to do with my cURLfile creation but have spent hours trying to pinpoint it.

**What could be causing this issue?**

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution . I reworked the request using the Guzzle client again and eventually had success. Here's a copy of my solution:

```
    // instantiate Guzzle http request
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

    // provide an fopen resource
    $filepath = 'public/'.$fileName;
    $body = fopen($fileName, 'r');

    // make the request
    $res = $client->request('POST', 'https://api.website.com', [
        'auth' => [
            getenv('USERNAME'),
            getenv('PASSWORD')
        ],
        'body' => $body
    ]);

    echo ("STATUS CODE: ");
    echo $res->getStatusCode();
//        200
```